Double the xticklabel distance to make it match y scale
I have this simple code:
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Gráficos de barras
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, colormap={RedToGreen}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,0,0); rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,0)}}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikz} % Usar gráficos

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.10)},anchor=north},
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.14,.5)},anchor=south},
                xlabel={$\sum Ejercicios_{Hechos}$},
                ylabel={Calificación sobre 10},
                xmin=0, xmax=10.5,
                ymin=0, ymax=10,
                xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
                ytick={0,2.5,5,7.5,10},
                legend pos=north west,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                ymajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                axis lines = left,
                colormap name=RedToGreen,
            ]
            \addplot [scatter, mesh, mark=*,ultra thick,scatter/use  mapped color={fill=mapped color, draw=mapped color}] 
            table [x=x, y=y] {
                x   y
                0   0.00
                    1   0.00
                    2   1.43
                    3   4.29
                    4   7.14
                    5   10.00
                };
             \addplot[mark=*,fill=blue] coordinates {(7,5)} node[pin=135:{$(7/10\:Ejercicios\rightarrow5)$}]{} ;
            %\legend{Nota ejercicios}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}

With this code, I get this plot:

Is it possible to make every xticklabel scale to 2, so the x axis scale goes up to 10 even though the values go up to 5??

What about setting xmax=7 (or 5 even, but then the blue dot will move out of the visible area)? Or maybe I don't quite get wnat you want the output to be ...

Or maybe you want xtick={0,1,...,10}?

I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can probably just change xmax=10.5 to something like xmax=5.5. To avoid that the blue dot becomes invisible as it is moved outside the plot area and will be clipped away, you an set clip=false that will make it visible again.
Note that pgfplots already loads tikz, so there is no need to load it again. I'd also use \mathrm{} (or maybe \mathit{} for italics) for text in math, because the kerning is not optimal otherwise.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Gráficos de barras
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12, 
    colormap={RedToGreen}{
        rgb255(0cm)=(255,0,0); 
        rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,0)
    },
    width=8cm, compat=1.9
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            x label style={
                at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.10)}, 
                anchor=north
            },
            y label style={
                at={(axis description cs:-0.14,.5)}, 
                anchor=south
            },
            xlabel={$\sum \mathrm{Ejercicios}_{\mathrm{Hechos}}$},
            ylabel={Calificación sobre 10},
            xmin=0, xmax=5.5,
            ymin=0, ymax=10,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
            ytick={0,2.5,5,7.5,10},
            legend pos=north west,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            axis lines=left,
            colormap name=RedToGreen,
            clip=false,
        ]
        \addplot[scatter, mesh, mark=*, ultra thick, 
            scatter/use mapped color={
                fill=mapped color, draw=mapped color
            }] 
            table [x=x, y=y] {
                x   y
                0   0.00
                1   0.00
                2   1.43
                3   4.29
                4   7.14
                5   10.00
            };
        \addplot[mark=*, fill=blue] coordinates {(7,5)} 
            node[pin=215:{$(7/10\:\mathrm{Ejercicios}\rightarrow5)$}] {};
        %\legend{Nota ejercicios}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Exactly, Setting up the xmax to 5.
